# Why can't I access my jQuery collection once it has been used to wrap another element?

Tags: jquery

Look at this code:

```
var b = $('<div id="b" />');
$('#a').wrap(b);
b.css({ border: '5px solid red' });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CFwC7/).

The element stored under `b` will *not* have a border.

Is there any way to access `b` still once it has been used to wrap another element?

Or should I do `b = $('#b')` again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think jQuery actually uses the same instance of "b" to wrap it. You would need to overwrite "b" with the one that was created to do the wrap.

```
var b = $('<div id="b" />');

b = $('#a').wrap(b).parent();

b.css({ border: '5px solid red' });
```

I suppose the reason is that if `a` was a class instead of an ID, and there were several of them, you wouldn't be able to use the same element to individually wrap each `.a`.

So it must make a clone of `b` that it uses to do the wrap.

Comment: Not, your code works because the second line "b" receive the element "b" from DOM. However, in the first line, the "b" refer to a memory. When you create element in memory, after you sent it to DOM your changes in element in memory doesn't affect DOM. This is the true reason.

Comment: @Gustavo: Changes made to an element "in memory" take effect whether or not it has been added to the DOM. [Test an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/xR8FY/)

Comment: ... [here's the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/manipulation.js#L99-103) for `wrap()`. Notice that it just calls `wrapAll` on each element. So [here's the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/manipulation.js#L58-59) for `wrapAll()` where it makes the clone of the element being used as the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

> var b = $('');
>
> $('#a').wrap(b).css({ border: '5px
>   solid red' });

Comment: This adds the css style to `#a` and `b` doesn't contain an element to be used for the wrap.

Answer (score 1):

The b contain the element in memory, after DOM append, you send b to DOM at second line and before call css() by the element referenced by "b" and not by the DOM match.

Comment: The Alexander and RightSaidFred's code restores the b from DOM and its these codes works.